# Block Style Not Applying in Editor

Tags: block-editor, editor

I've created the following block style, based off of core/paragraph, and included inline styles which display on the frontend page but not in the editor. How do I apply these styles to the editor view of this block style?

```
register_block_style(
    'core/paragraph',
        array(
            'name'  => 'intro-paragraph',
            'label' => __( 'Intro Graph (To be used for the introductory paragraph of a page.)', 'intro-paragraph' ),
            'inline_style' => '.is-style-intro-paragraph {
                                    color: #2e2e2e;
                                    font-family: "Domine", serif;
                                    font-size: 23px;
                                    line-height: 40px;
                                    margin-bottom: 40px;
                                }',
        )

    );
```